# How can I loop through a jquery object and store values in an array?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to create jquery objects then compare those objects to see if any two are alike meaning same properties. Then I want to alert the user and prevent the page from posting.  So far when I click I get only one iteration of the alert box that I'm using to test the code.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Thanks for any ideas!

```
$("#saveBtn").click(function () {
    function widget(i, o) {
        this.Index = index;
        this.Object = o;
    } 
    $("input[name='selectedCourses']:checked").each(function (i) {
        alert("The index is " + i + " and the value is " + $(this).val());
        checked.push(new widget(i, parseInt($(this).val())));
    });
});
```

Comment: check console for errors. i bet your `checked.push(new widget(i, parseInt($(this).val())));` line fails. if you have no errors in the console, it means that your `$("input[name='selectedCourses']:checked")` selector only returns one element

Answer (score 0):

well i only see one issue with your code so i assume thats the cause of the problem,

your function

```
function widget(i, o) {
    this.Index = index;
    this.Object = o;
}
```

is assigning some non existent `index` var. try changing it to:

```
function widget(i, o) {
    this.Index = i;
    this.Object = o;
}
```

Comment: I changed the index but the alert only appears once and with the first index and value.

Comment: put another alert after the `checked.push(new widget(i, parseInt($(this).val())));` line and see if it pops up